# ViewBag, cyrillic strings and Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, encoding

I use ASP.NET MVC 5 and I have a simple action with string parameter:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string cyrillicParam)
{
    // here I see cyrillicParam as "�����������"
    // some code
    return View();
}
```

If I pass some cyrillic text as cyrillicParam this parameter's encoding becomes broken. This problem appears only in IE and not in other browsers. Does anybody know how to fix this bug? Unusually encoding url is not appropriate solution for me.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce. IE 11.0.9600 works fine. Make sure that in View -> Encoding menu are selected "Unicode (UTF-8)".

Comment: @AntonKedrov encoding using in IE  is UTF-8. But problem remains.

Comment: If you hardcode that string in cshtml, then will it display correctly?

Comment: @AntonKedrov I was wrong. The problem is hiding not in ViewBag. Now I've updated my question.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce it either. Is this value coming from browser or is it hardcoded in Route object? Or might be `MyAction` invoked by another action?